Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'idToken'
want to add a UserID claim to your Azure B2C token when using Auth0 as a custom IdP.
When testing the Run User Flow I get errors saying I don't had the "userID.
In Auth0, I created an Action and a Trigger at "post-login". The rule is:
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  const { user, context } = event;

  // Ensure idToken is available and not undefined
  if (context.idToken) {
    context.idToken[0].UserID = user.user_id;
  } else {
    console.error("idToken is undefined in the context object.");
  }

  return { user, context };
};

however get the error:
An invalid response was received : 'Error: access_denied,Error Description: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'idToken')'

however get the error:" An invalid response was received : 'Error: access_denied,Error Description: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'idToken')'`"
really need help
add a claim for UserID in token

Have you added the claim to the B2C token? Also, I'm not sure what library you're using in your client but it doesn't look right that you're referencing into idToken like it's an array then trying to access a property on it to access the claim. I think you need to provide more details about what you've done in B2C, what the library you're using client-side is and/or what context.idToken is expected to be that this point otherwise the question might end up closed for not enough details.
